# Umbraco getpropertyvalue does not work on live

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a helper method that works perfectly on local, however does not want to work on dev server. I used all sorts of logs to find out where the problem lies. It does get the current node and the homepage as well, however when it tries to use the `GetPropertyValue<Dictionary<string, string>>` it comes back as null.

Error message `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` as I am trying to use this value later down the line.

Code:

```
            var helper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
            var homepage = helper.TypedContent(UmbracoContext.Current.PageId).AncestorOrSelf(1);
            var test = homepage.Children.First(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "test");
            Dictionary<string, string> testDict = test.GetPropertyValue<Dictionary<string, string>>("testOptions");
```

Any ideas?

It finds everything even test node, but testDict is null

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what type is in `test.GetPropertyValue("testOptions")` ?

Comment: What kind of property editor is used on testOptions? Also try to republish the website to clear the server side cache: go to http://yoursite.com/Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true

Comment: Cache has been cleared, key value pair property editor used and `test.GetPropertyValue("testOptions")` comes back as null.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, it could be one of the following:

- The property isn't on the live site node, check the doctype to make sure the property exists, it could also be that there's a typo in the field alias on live, or the field alias is different
- There is is a property converter that handles the conversion that hasn't been deployed to live

Check both of those to see if that's the issue. If that's not it, just get the value of the field as a string and see what's in there, is the field empty, or is there something in there?